# Using Publish composite for shared joins: pull out user's posts + comments

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

Im able to show list of posts of a specific user but not able to show posts that contains comments by a specific user.

**The example in the official links uses this hierarchy** [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333124/meteor-reactive-data-query-for-comments-with-usernames-and-pictures/28334818#28334818)

**For my problem, the hierarchy is:**

```
all posts -> 
(children)
-> find all post by user
-> find all comment by user
   (children)
   -> find post that has id that matches comments
```

What I have so far..

**Publish Composite lines**

```
Meteor.publishComposite('user', function(_id) {  
    return { 
      find: function() { 
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: _id}, { fields: { profile: 1, username: 1} });
      },
      children: [
        {
          find: function(user) { return Posts.find({ userId: user._id }); }
        },
        {
          find: function(user) { return Comments.find({ _id: user._id }); } 
              children: [
                {
                  find: function(comment) { return Posts.find({ _id: comment.postId }); }
                } 
              ] 
        }
      ]
    };
});
```

**In the template**

```
Template.usersShow.helpers({    
  user: function () {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: Router.current().params._id });
  }
});
```

**In the router**

```
Router.route('/users/:_id', { name: 'users.show',
  waitOn:function(){
    // console.log(this.params._id);
    return Meteor.subscribe('user', this.params._id);
  }
});
```

**html**

```
  {{#with user}}
    <div class>{{ profile.name }}</div>    <!-- name appears --> 
    {{#ionList}}
      {{#each post}}
        {{> postItem}}
      {{/each}}
    {{/ionList}}
  {{/with}}
```

Answer (score 1):

what i see at first glimpse is:

- You don't need to publish `pullData` at all, `user` publication can do the job you mention in 1)
- in your code try following pattern to find `posts` and `comments` belonging to `user`:

`children: [
        {
          find: function(user) { return Posts.find({ authorId: user._id }); }
        },
        {
          find: function(user) { return Comments.find({ authorId: user._id }); } 
        }
      ]`

Just replace `authorId` with appropriate field name in your `Post` and `Comment` schemes.

I found `publishComposite` excellent solution for publishing joins in Meteor.

[Join in Meteor with publishComposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31177257/join-in-meteor-with-publishcomposite/31179100#31179100)

Hope this helps,

Alex

P.S. I have re-read your edited question and would like to suggest you to:

- split your app in views (read Templates), e.g. `AllPosts`, `MyPosts` `TopTenPosts`, `PostsByUser`, `PostWithComments`, `MyCommentedPosts` etc.
- define *what* every view has to display, and convert *what* into subscription
- define publication (you may want to stub it somehow) for every subscription
- ensure your views are matching expectations
- refactor publications so they pull only necessary data from mongo for particular view

TDD to rescue.

Comment: Hi, good to know its on track. How do I then reflect the posts in the html? 
So for example to show all the posts written by the user. My html doesnt show anything and no error message

Comment: in browser console try Posts.find().fetch() and Comments.find().fetch() to check if published data arrived to browser and available for templates. Then make template helpers for 'posts` and 'comments' returning Posts.find() and Comments.find() accordingly. And last, take {{> postItem}} list out of {{#with user}} - you don't have posts and comments under user object.

Comment: i have update it for the Ids. Not too good with the naming conventions. I am looking to pull the posts that has the comments, and not the comments themselves. Is it harder and how do I do iit? I have an additional line under `Comments.find` but nothing shows up and console logs empty `[ ]`.

Comment: In order to show **posts commented by user** you may want to change your query so `posts` will be children of `comments` and userId will be a `filter` parameter to find `comments`. Please check link above for example.